# Is there a way to change the font color of a piece of text ONLY on beamer mode?

Tags: beamer, color

I'm building a `beamer` presentation and would like to have some parts of the text shown as red on specific slides, but ONLY on `beamer` mode (as opposed to `handout` mode). I have tried the following:

```
\color<beamer:2>{red}{some text}
```

The above worked well on `beamer` mode (the text was shown in red on slide 2, and black on the other slides). However, in `handout` mode, the text is red.

Is there a way for the text to be red on slide 2 on `beamer` mode, black on all other slides, and also black on `handout` mode?

Comment: `\color<handout:2>{red}{some text}` ?

Comment: Thanks, but no, I want the exact opposite. I want that piece of text to be BLACK in handout mode.

Oddly enough, your suggestion makes the text red in beamer mode too. Is something wrong with my xcolor package or is that supposed to happen?

Comment: In the case this doesn't help, I think it would be better to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, so that those who want to help you don't have to make it themselves.

Comment: OK, here you go: http://pastebin.com/E5WEFtA5

This works well on beamer mode, but the red text remains red in handout mode.

Comment: @Gabriela Next time, you can simply edit your question and add the code there ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
\color<beamer:2|handout:0>{red}{some text}
```

The thing to remember about overlay specifications is that the *default* assumption is to take the action.  So when in handout mode, TeX sees `\color<beamer:2>{red}{some text}` and asks "I'm in `handout` mode, is there any reason *not* to execute `\color`?".  To which the response is "No" as there's no specific `handout` declaration.  Putting in `handout:0` says "In handout mode only do this on slide `0`".  As there is never a slide `0`, this effectively says "In handout mode *don't do this*".

See also the following for similar issues with specifying overlays if you find examples helpful to learn about things like this:

- [Deactivate all \alt,\uncover in beamer (for printing)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6705/86)
- [How to exclude certain slides from handout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35027/86) (warning: pictures of cats)
- [Can I declare a different overlay specification in different beamer modes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13087/86)
- [How can I distribute beamer overlayareas in handout mode across multiple frames?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6582/86)

Comment: Till Tantau gave us `pgfkeys` and overlay specifications.  Marvelous innovations!

Comment: I was wondering if there is a command to globally specify the handout color.