# Beamer : process only the last slide of a frame

Tags: beamer

For a complex frame with several slides that order is alraidy correctly set, I'd like to process only last frame to tune placement details and avoid a long processing time.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\includeonlyframes{current}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label=current]

\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am sorry, maybe it's just me, but I cannot understand the question. What do you mean by "procced" (or "proceed" as in the title of the question)?

Comment: Latex compiles only the last slide, the document has only one page. Please rephrase my question in a better english. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean "process" instead of "proceed" ?

Comment: For me, the result has 4 pages.

Comment: Indeed 4 slides, but I want just the last, to avoid a long pocessing time.

Comment: You can use `\documentclass[handout]{beamer}` to get one page per frame.

Comment: @Marijn Does this speed up processing?

Comment: @AlexG yes, definitely, because there is a lot of processing for the intermediate pages that is not incremental or reusable. I'm not sure this is what the OP intended, though.

Comment: It is what the OP is looking for. It process directly the last slide without previous slides incremental things that appear step by step on each slide. Feel free to write an answer.

Comment: In that case the question is a duplicate of e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6705/deactivate-all-alt-uncover-in-beamer-for-printing or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1423/is-there-a-nice-way-to-compile-a-beamer-presentation-without-the-pauses/