# Beamer: error while making handouts

Tags: beamer, errors

I'm trying to make a handout version of my presentation: i.e., a version with only the last slide on every sequence of slides. After reading around I installed `pgfpages` and changed:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
```

to

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
```

However, I get the error:

```
! Class beamer Error: Overprints may not overlap.
```

(I'll note that the original version of the presentation compiles, no problem.)

Ideas? Am I don't something wrong, is there a different way to make handouts?

Comment: I'm guessing that somewhere deep in your presentation you use the `overprint` environment.  In all the `\onslide`s (except the one you want shown) add the overlay `handout:0`.  That is, if you have `\onslide<2-3>` change it to `\onslide<2-3|handout:0>`.

Comment: That works: do you want to formally answer the question so I can vote you up?

Comment: Done.  (I didn't post it as an answer at first as I wasn't completely sure that this would fix it.  There may have been something else as well.)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is due to how beamer collapses slides for the `handout` version.  Unless told otherwise, just about *everything* ends up on the `handout` version.  Apart from a few cases where it tries to do things correctly (such as `\alt` commands), it doesn't try to be too clever and work out what clashes with what.

(This is a Good Thing: these decisions are often tricky and should be made by a human.  Preferably the one writing the presentation.)

But it can be that you have stuff on a slide that shouldn't be shown together.  A simple example might be when using some `\only`s for a more complicated set of alternate texts.  Something like, `\(\pi = \only<1>{3}\only<2>{22/7}\only<3>{3.1415}\)`.  Then its clear that only one of these should be on the `handout` slide, but beamer will put all of these on by default.

Fortunately, beamer makes it easy to control what goes on a `handout` frame.  An overlay specification can have a "handout-specific" part, which is of the form `handout:XYZ`.  Different parts of the specification are separated by bars, thus a complicated specification could be: `<2-3|handout:0|trans:1>`.  The "default" is for `beamer` so this reads: "In the `beamer` mode, show this on slides 2 and 3, in `handout` **don't show it at all**, in the `transparency` mode, show this on slide 1.".

Note the "**don't show it at all**" in the above.  Specifying slide `0` means "don't show".

In the specific case, you are using the `overprint` environment.  Within this one uses `\onslide`s to separate the content and these must have mutually-exclusive overlay specifications (since the material is to be specified on different slides).  Since the `handout` mode collapses them all, even if they are mutually exclusive in `beamer` they aren't in `handout`.  So we have to make them mutually exclusive again by putting in the "don't show" specification.  As it is usual to have only one slide-per-frame in the `handout` version, this means putting the `handout:0` specification on all of the `\onslide`s except one.

Thus inside the `overprint` environment, change things like:

```
\onslide<2-3>
```

to

```
\onslide<2-3|handout:0>
```

Comment: What if one wants in the handout to generate different slides for the different steps of the overprint instead of choosing one?

Comment: i.e. this would actually mean to temporary disable the handout mode for a single frame. Is it possible?

Comment: @gigabytes See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6582/86, I think it does what you want.