# Can overlays be activated for a single frame in handout mode in beamer?

Tags: beamer, overlays, handout

I'm working on a long beamer document and each frame has lots of overlays. To make my workflow faster, I'm using `handout` mode. However, sometimes when I'm working on a frame I want to test whether or not the overlays are working properly. I'm curious if it is possible to activate overlays for a single frame in `handout` mode.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}

  \frametitle{Happy Without Overlays Here}

  \begin{block}{First Block}<+->
    Foo bar.
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{Second Block}<+->
    Foo bar.
  \end{block}

\end{frame}



\begin{frame}[?magic?]

  \frametitle{I Want Overlays Here}

  \begin{block}{First Block}<+->
    Foo \pause bar.
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{Second Block}<+->
    Spam \pause eggs.
  \end{block}

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}

  \frametitle{Also Happy Without Overlays Here}

  \begin{block}{First Block}<+->
    Foo bar.
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{Second Block}<+->
    Foo bar.
  \end{block}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Does it helps? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6582/1952

Comment: @Ignassi Not really. The technique there would allow me to display a specific overlay from the frame in handout mode. I want *all* overlays from one particular frame to display in handout mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could temporarily switch to a different mode:

```
\documentclass[
handout
]{beamer}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}

  \frametitle{Happy Without Overlays Here}

  \begin{block}{First Block}<+->
    Foo bar.
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{Second Block}<+->
    Foo bar.
  \end{block}

\end{frame}


\makeatletter
\gdef\beamer@currentmode{beamer}
\makeatother
\begin{frame}

  \frametitle{I Want Overlays Here}

  \begin{block}{First Block}<+->
    Foo \uncover<+->{bar.}
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{Second Block}<+->
    Spam \uncover<+->{eggs.}
  \end{block}

\end{frame}
\makeatletter
\gdef\beamer@currentmode{handout}
\makeatother
\begin{frame}

  \frametitle{Also Happy Without Overlays Here}

  \begin{block}{First Block}<+->
    Foo bar.
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{Second Block}<+->
    Foo bar.
  \end{block}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you!

Now I'm interested in wrapping this into a new environment but can't quite figure out how:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651069/newdocumentenvironment-ignoring-gdef-statement-in-beamer